# Cannot add a directory to a new github project

Tags: git

I'm pretty new to github (and `.git` in general!), and have followed the basic guides on the github website on how to add an existing project into a new git repo, but I can't get a folder to be added:

```
G:\gittest> Get-ChildItem


    Directory: G:\gittest


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        14/08/2016     15:49            about us
-a---        10/08/2016     23:22       5899 index.html
```

So then I run the appropriate `git` commands:

```
G:\gittest> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in G:/gittest/.git/
G:\gittest [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> git add . -v
add 'index.html'
G:\gittest [master +1 ~0 -0 ~]> git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   index.html

G:\gittest [master +1 ~0 -0 ~]>
```

So, why isn't the `about us` folder being added?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git` tracks *files*, not folders. Folders are hashed based on the files they contain, because a folder in itself is not a entity. A folder is just part of a file's path. When you add a file to "about us", `git` will automatically recognize the files inside "about us" and realize that "about us" is a folder.

`git` has no use and can't do anything with empty folders, because they hold no value.